# How much is 95000 rubles from 1897 worth in today's money?

Tags: russian-language, historical-context, anton-chekhov, uncle-vanya

In the Anton Chekhov play *Uncle Vanya*, Vanya said that the whole estate was bought for 95000 rubles. How much money would that be in today's market?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approximately 100,000,000 roubles.**

This is not a straightfoward conversion due to fluctuations in the value of the rouble after the collapse of communism.

This [historical currency converter](http://www.historicalstatistics.org/Currencyconverter.html) runs up to 2015 and makes various calculations based on the comparison of the value of important goods and services. It has this to say about the conversion:

> 95000 Russian rouble [1880-1917] in year 1897 could buy the same amount of consumer goods and services in Sweden as 83676035.7401576 Russian rouble [1998-2015] could buy in Sweden in year 2015. This comparison should be used if the purpose of the analysis is to compare absolute worth over time rather than relative worth.
>
> Another way to compare the worth of money in different periods is to estimate how much labour power an amount of money could buy. 95000 Russian rouble [1880-1917] in year 1897 was the amount a male worker in Sweden received in wage for 685682.3116743009 hours work. A male worker in Sweden in 2015 received 1031940763.8783861 Russian rouble [1998-2015] in wage for 685682.3116743009 hours worked. This comparison should be used if the purpose of the analysis is to compare relative worth over time rather than absolute worth.
>
> 95000 Russian rouble [1880-1917] in year 1897 could buy 72486.53282777914 gram gold. The price of 72486.53282777914 gram gold in year 2015 was 164057467.64390242 Russian rouble [1998-2015].
>
> 95000 Russian rouble [1880-1917] in year 1897 could buy 2479039.422710049 gram silver. The price of 2479039.422710049 gram silver in year 2015 was 75838147.48275831 Russian rouble [1998-2015].

The value for goods and services - 83,676,035 - seems like an appropriate one to use.

According to [this other conversion tool](https://www.inflationtool.com/russian-ruble/), which doesn't go back to 1897, inflation since 2015 would make that amount worth 104,500,640 roubles today.